# Does the Israeli military have a legal right to shoot at anyone within the Gaza Strip that they suspect of being a militant of Hamas?

Tags: criminal-law, military, laws-of-war, politics, terrorism

Same question as [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96829/does-the-israeli-military-have-a-legal-right-to-shoot-at-anyone-within-the-gaza) but changing the qualifier 'member' to 'militant' based on the following comment:

> I guess what the OP *wanted* to ask is the shooting of people who are suspected of being Hamas militants, i.e. presumably combatants, who may not be clearly identified as such at the time. A suspected Hamas member with a clearly visible rifle is one thing, how about a suspected Hamas member carrying a box with unclear contents into a suspected fighting position, or a suspected Hamas member who was observed talking to another suspected Hamas member who is believed to be a military commander ... – o.m. Oct 31, 2023 at 6:43

Now the changing:

> In regard to the ground incursion of the Gaza Strip by the Israeli military, I would like to know if it is stated somewhere in either international law, or in Israel law, or in the Geneva Convention, that members of the Israeli military have a legal right to shoot at anyone within the Gaza Strip that they suspect of being a ***militant*** of Hamas.

> Or in another way of looking at this, after this Israeli-Hamas war has ended, could a member(s) of the Israeli military face being court-martialed, or face being prosecuted by the International Criminal Court (ICC), if it is proven that the military member(s) had killed a citizen(s) of the Gaza Strip who was never a ***militant*** of Hamas?

> Does the Israeli military have a legal right to shoot at anyone within the Gaza Strip that they suspect of being a ***militant*** of Hamas?

Also adding these:

1. Around 8:31 of this [2024Feb01 interview of Ben Shapiro by Piers Morgan](https://youtu.be/Dgyh8NX7pZU?t=511), Piers asks if it's legal that Israel dresses up as hospital staff and then kills supposed Hamas operatives/militants/members.
2. [How is Israel's situation vs Hamas in Gaza/Palestine remarkable when it comes to evidence?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/101503/how-is-israels-situation-vs-hamas-in-gaza-palestine-remarkable-when-it-comes-to)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Israeli military have a legal right to shoot at anyone within the Gaza Strip that they suspect of being a member of Hamas?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96829/does-the-israeli-military-have-a-legal-right-to-shoot-at-anyone-within-the-gaza)

Comment: Law is irrelevant when the people who don't like you have lots of guns and are willing to use them.